# Command prompt appears in background when i deploy published .NET 6.0 application

Tags: c#, .net, reactiveui, avaloniaui

I am trying to publish an application on cross platform i.e, on mac and Windows. I successfully developed and deployed for mac but when I publish and deploy it for win-x64 (Windows), the application opens but there's command prompt in background and I need to fix that.

[image]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <BuiltInComInteropSupport>true</BuiltInComInteropSupport>
        <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
        <PublishTrimmed> true </PublishTrimmed>
        <AvaloniaUseCompiledBindingsByDefault>true</AvaloniaUseCompiledBindingsByDefault>
        <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
        <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
        <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
        <ApplicationIcon>CompcastApplication.ico</ApplicationIcon>
        <Version>1.0.0</Version>
        <NoWin32Manifest>true</NoWin32Manifest>  
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CFBundleName>EnvironmentSetter</CFBundleName>
        <CFBundleExecutable>EnvironmentSetter</CFBundleExecutable>
        <CFBundleIdentifier>com.gani.comcomcastapp</CFBundleIdentifier>
        <CFBundleShortVersionString>$(Version)</CFBundleShortVersionString>
        <CFBundleIconFile>Comcast.icns</CFBundleIconFile>
        <CFBundlePackageType>APPL</CFBundlePackageType>
        <NSPrincipalClass>NSApplication</NSPrincipalClass>
        <NSHighResolutionCapable>True</NSHighResolutionCapable>
        <NSHumanReadableCopyright>©2023 Ganiiiii</NSHumanReadableCopyright>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Avalonia.Themes.Fluent" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Avalonia" Version="0.10.18" />
        <PackageReference Include="Avalonia.Desktop" Version="0.10.18" />
        <!--Condition below is needed to remove Avalonia.Diagnostics package from build output in Release configuration.-->
        <PackageReference Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" Include="Avalonia.Diagnostics" Version="0.10.18" />
        <PackageReference Include="Avalonia.ReactiveUI" Version="0.10.18" />
        <PackageReference Include="DotNet.Bundle" Version="0.9.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="MessageBox.Avalonia" Version="2.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NSubsys" Version="1.0.0">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <NoWin32Manifest>true</NoWin32Manifest>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I tried using this and I tried using runtime identifiers as well but the command prompt won't go away.

Comment: I would check this: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/5059